# ManyToMany Query (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, many-to-many

How might I query through a ManytoMany field to list the shows an Artist has played (along with their genre which has been completed). I am fairly new to Django with just finishing up the Tango with Django tutorial, but what I have so far is below.

### models.py

```
class Genre(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


class Artist(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False)
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='artist_photos', blank=True)
  logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='artist_logos', blank=True)
  genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
  twitter = models.URLField(blank=True)
  facebook = models.URLField(blank=True)
  instagram = models.URLField(blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Venue(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False)
  logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='venue_logos', blank=True)
  capacity = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  zip_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  website = models.URLField(blank=True)
  twitter = models.URLField(blank=True)
  facebook = models.URLField(blank=True)
  instagram = models.URLField(blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Show(models.Model):
  venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
  date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
  attendance = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
  bands = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
```

### views.py

```
def artists(request):
  context = RequestContext(request)
  artists = Artist.objects.order_by('name')
  shows = Show.objects.order_by('-date_time')
  # artist_shows = Show.objects.filter(????????)

context_dic = {'artists': artists, 'shows': shows}

return render_to_response('artistdb/artists.html', context_dic, context)
```

### artist.html

```
<h2>Artists</h2>
{% if artists %}
    <ul>
        {% for artist in artists %}
            <li>{{ artist.name }}<br />
                <ul>
                {% for g in artist.genre.all %}
                    <li>{{ g.name }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
            <br />
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>   
{% else %}
    There are no artist.
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the shows that an artist has played, you can do this:

```
artist = Artist.objects.get(name="johndt6")

artist.show_set.all() # Will return all shows related to the artist
```

A recommendation is to set a `related_name` argument on your foreign keys and many to many fields. So, under the Show model, the many to many relation to artist would read:

```
bands = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, related_name="shows")
```

Then, you could query an artist's shows as follows:

```
artist.shows.all()  # Will return all of the artists shows
```

You can also use normal queries if you wish:

```
shows = Show.objects.filter(bands__in=artist)  # Will return all of an artist's shows
```

However, this isn't quite as nice as using Django's built in relations.

[See documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Comment: `related_name` was definitely what I was missing. This is going to help a bunch moving forward. Thanks!